# Why can't Specman import two files with the same name?

Tags: specman

Let's say that I have 2 files, both called `foo.e`, but residing in different directories. The documentation mentions that it isn't possible to import both. because once the first file is loaded, the second will be skipped.

Is this just a limitation of Specman or is there a deeper reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a rather philosophical question - whether this is a limitation or a feature.

In *e* there is a notion of a *module*. Each loaded or compiled *e* file becomes a module, and the source file name (without the extension) becomes the modules name.
And module names should be unique.
I can see a few reasons for that.
First, module names (prefixed by "@") are shown in many situations to refer to a specific module. For example, in messages or in error messages, to provide a source reference.
Second, modules are represented in the Reflection API, by the **rf_module** object, and those objects can be queried by name.

Another, maybe deeper, reason that I can see, is the way in which **import** statements are handled. When there are two or more **import** statements referring to the same file, only the first one takes effect (bringing the content of the respective module into the system), and the other ones are ignored. Now, if it was allowed to have several modules with the same name, it would lead to the following issue: how do we decide whether a given **import** statement refers to the *same* file as some previous **import** statement (and thus should be ignored), or it refers to a different file which just happens to have the same name? Just comparing the exact explicitly stated path would not be enough, because the same file can be referred to by different pathes (relative, absolute, via symbolic links, and so on).

With all these reasons mentioned, one could still claim that they are just technical (rather than conceptual), and those issues could have been handled in some way. So, I cannot give a definite answer whether it's a limitation or not.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, you're just he person I was hoping would answer this.